# SSH session time tracking

Tags: bash, ssh

I was wondering if there was a way to detect which users had an active ssh session, or rather how long they have been logged in.

Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to track the time used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `w` and `last`.

Answer (score 0):

Each ssh session has a corresponding tty process. Just check how long it has been running.